# Replace value in the specified range in the file

Tags: shell, sed, pattern-matching

I would like to replace value in the specified range in the file using `sed` command.

Let's say I have one file:

```
[red]
rose,garden,tree
[green]    
leaf,tree
[blue]
water,sea
```

I want to replace 'tree' as 'plant' in [green] block only, so that the output looks like:

```
[red]
rose,garden,tree
[green]    
leaf,plant
[blue]
water,sea
```

I used `sed -i 's/tree/plant/g' file1.txt` however it replaced all occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

I would `awk` for this:

```
$ awk '/^\[/ && f {f=0} /^\[green]/ {f=1} f{gsub("tree","plant")} 1' a
[red]
rose,garden,tree
[green]    
leaf,plant
[blue]
water,sea
```

#### Explanation

This sets a flag when you are inside the `[green]` block.

- `/^\[/ && f {f=0}` when a new line starting with `[` appears, unset the flag.
- `/^\[green]/ {f=1}` if the block is `[green]`, set the flag.
- `f{gsub("tree","plant")}` when the flag is set, replace all occurrences of `tree` with `plant`.
- `1` print the line, following `awk`'s default behaviour.

Comment: yep, see the explanation below

Answer (score 1):

This sed command will replace the text `tree` with `plant` only if it's present inside `[green]` block that is a block which starts with the  string `[green]` upto the line which starts with `[...]`.

```
$ sed '/^\[green\]/,/^\[[^]]*\]/ s/tree/plant/g' file
[red]
rose,garden,tree
[green]    
leaf,plant
[blue]
water,sea
```